# Multi Dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Require a 2D-vector with a pair(int, int) as elements.The following code gives SIGSEGV on running.How can it be resolved ?

```
int main()
{
vector< vector<pair<int, int> > >v;  
//vector< vector<pair<int, int> > >v(3), problem is resolved, but how ?


for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    v[i].push_back(make_pair(i, j));

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
 cout<<"\n";
 for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    cout<<"{"<<v[i][j].first<<", "<<v[i][j].second<<"}  ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "2D vectors" are just vectors. Figure out how to use  a vector, then you know how to use a "2d vector". Or "3D". Or more.

Comment: Have a look at what v(3) actually means.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, `v` contains solely nothing, so the SIGSEGV if received at

```
v[0].push_back(make_pair(0, 0)); // First loop
```

If you initialize `v` with a length of 3, then `v[0]` is a valid statement and won't cause a segmentation fault.

The following code should work if you don't initialize `v` with a size.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    vector<pair<int,int> > t;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        t.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
    v.push_back(std::move(t));
}
```

<sup>Thanks to *Zereges* for code improvement</sup>

Comment: `v.push_back(std::move(t))`

Comment: @Zereges Well, copying won't be too redundant with just a size of 3*3=9.

Answer (score 0):

> You are inserting wrong.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    v[i].push_back(make_pair(i, j));
```

> **Change your code of insertion like below to work properly:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        vector<pair<int, int>> vctr;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            vctr.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
        }
        v.push_back(vctr);
    }
```

> create a vector of pair, lets say: (vctr), then insert pair<**i,j**> in (vctr).
>   and then insert vctr to vector (v).